# MLP or RNN for Regression of Smooth Function (No Time Data)?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, time-series

My Problem consists of Input sequences in the form of $x=[B,z]$ and one output $y_i$ for each data point $x_i=[B,z_i]$. For one sequence/dataset $B$ is a constant, whereas $z$ is continously between 0 and 5.

In the moment I just train a standard MLP on this. However, I wonder if I can "help" my neural network because I know, that $y_i$ is a smooth function of $z_i$. This seems analog to a time series problem, where I computate my solution at $y_i(t=0)$ and use this information for the prediction of $y_i(t=1)$.

Am I right with this assumption? Can I use RNN or a combination of RNN with MLP for this?

Comment: Can you please edit your post to format the symbols and equations with mathjax to improve the readability? Moreover, the question in the title is very general. Please, put your **specific question** in the title.

Comment: Done and changed title

Comment: I think the best way is just to try it out. If it is in fact something like a time series RNN/LSTM can be helpful because in many applications (but not all) they yield good results when having sequence data.